# how to exclude whole property if they are null from Modelmapper

Tags: java, mapper, modelmapper

Does ModelMapper(http://modelmapper.org/) support what exclude property? If the value is null.

I just found PropertyMap out. but It is a constraint to me.
because I have to describe a specific property that I want.

Like this.

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<TestObject, TestObject>() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        when(Conditions.isNull()).skip().setName(source.getName());
        when(Conditions.isNull()).skip().set...(source.get...());
        when(Conditions.isNull()).skip().set...(source.get...());
        when(Conditions.isNull()).skip().set...(source.get...());
        when(Conditions.isNull()).skip().set...(source.get...());
        when(Conditions.isNull()).skip().set...(source.get...());
    }
});
```

In my case, I have a lot of property and verbose. 
How to exclude mapping property if they are null from all them.
Is there more comfortable solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can configure ModelMapper to ignore all properties that are null with the following configuration:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
```

It is useful, for example, for partial updates of a target object where you only want to copy those properties from the source object that are not null.

Comment: Thanks, That's I wanted.

Comment: This isn't working for me idk why :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359427/modelmapper-not-ignoring-null-values

Comment: I have `int` fields in my DTO/Entity. Since `int` can only be a zero, and cannot be null, is there a way to skip values that are equal to zero ?

Comment: @med.b you can use the Integer wrapper class instead of int primitive type

Comment: Is there any solution of int fields if they are coming from third party jar and can not be modified.