# ModelMapper not ignoring null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I want to do a partial update on one of my entities but if one propertie is null then the entity to be updated gets that value set to null too. I want that if a property from the source is null then to keep the one from the source.

I have tried this but no luck:

```
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
        modelMapper.createTypeMap(String.class, Date.class);
        modelMapper.addConverter(new StringToDate());
        modelMapper.addConverter(new DateToString());
        return modelMapper;
    }
```

Then I update my object like this:

```
    @Override
    public void editUser(final User user) {
        UserDocument userDocument = this.usersRepository.findByIdAndActivo(user.getId(), true)
                .orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);

        userDocument = this.modelMapper.map(user, UserDocument.class);
        this.usersRepository.save(userDocument);
    }
```

The `user` object has 1 property set at null while the object `userDocument` has it with a value, then when I save it in the database that value is gone (because it has transformed into null).

What can be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: setting userDocument = assigns it to a reference to the output  of ModelMapper.map, and thus loses any information that were in it previously (when it referred to a different location). If you want to preserve things and copy the nonnull, you need to create a method of USerDocument that takes another UserDocument as a parameter and does the updating to "this" for the non-null fields of the parameter

Comment: what's the purpose of this configuration then? modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull()) @JeremyKahan

Comment: that is a fair question, and I am not sure. Oh, I see you figured it out. It helps with merging but not creating something fresh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so that configuration isn't for the purpose I thought it was.

I've solved the issue by merging the updated object with the old one like this:

```
    @Override
    public void editUser(final User user) {
        UserDocument userDocument = this.usersRepository.findByIdAndActivo(user.getId(), true)
                .orElseThrow(UserNotFoundException::new);

        this.modelMapper.map(user, userDocument);
        this.usersRepository.save(userDocument);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve in this way:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);

        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Mybatis framework? You have not set selective save --selective

`<insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="com.zjl.domain">
    insert into table_name
    <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
    <if test="id != null">
    id,
    </if>
    <if test="createDate != null">
    create_date,
    </if>
    <if test="modifiedDate != null">
    modified_date,
    </if>
    </trim>
    <trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
    <if test="id != null">
    #{id,jdbcType=BIGINT},
    </if>
    <if test="createDate != null">
    #{createDate,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
    </if>
    <if test="modifiedDate != null">
    #{modifiedDate,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
    </if>
    </trim>
</insert>`

Comment: No, it's MongoDB. I don't think that is the issue anyways. It should use the destination's fields when the source's ones are null